# Swift PDF render any UIView or UIViewController PDFKit

Tags: swift, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I made some research, I found that I can draw Image, Strings, Shapes with the `PDFKit` library. Is there any easy way to draw a `UIView` or the view of a `UIViewController` inside the PDF document?

I prefer a Swift answer, but I will accept Objective-C too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIView as well as the view contained into the UIViewController, can be rendered with the layer:

Get the context:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
```

UIView :

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
view.layer.render(in: context)
```

UIViewController

```
controller.loadViewIfNeeded()
controller.view.layer.render(in: context)
```

Full working script:

```
let pdfMetadata =
[
    kCGPDFContextCreator: "MyAppName",
    kCGPDFContextAuthor: "TheAuthor"
]
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath, CGRect.zero, pdfMetadata)

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

controller.loadViewIfNeeded()
controller.view.layer.render(in: context)

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```